Blazorise Validation message based on response from API
I have a Blazor application which is using Blazorise. I have a password reset dialog which works great, however when sending the password to the server I do a check to verify the password has not been used before. When it has, I want to display a message under the text field. How do I do that with a Blazorise Validation and still maintain the original validation?

<Fields>
    <Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
        <FieldLabel RequiredIndicator>Password</FieldLabel>
        <Validation Validator="@ValidatePassword">
            <TextEdit @bind-Text="@User.Password" Placeholder="Enter a Password" MaxLength="50" Role="TextRole.Password">
                <Feedback>
                    <ValidationError>Invalid password. Passwords must be between 8 and 30 characters long, one number, one lower and one upper case letter, and one special character.</ValidationError>
                </Feedback>
            </TextEdit>
        </Validation>
    </Field>
</Fields>
<Fields>
    <Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
        <FieldLabel RequiredIndicator>Confirm Password</FieldLabel>
        <Validation Validator="@ConfirmPassword">
            <TextEdit @bind-Text="@User.ConfirmPassword" Placeholder="Retype password" MaxLength="50" Role=" TextRole.Password">
                <Feedback>
                    <ValidationError>Password does not match!</ValidationError>
                </Feedback>
            </TextEdit>
        </Validation>
    </Field>
</Fields>
    
    

@code {
const string passwordPattern = @"^(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.\d)(?=.[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,30}$";
    void ValidatePassword(ValidatorEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(e.Value), passwordPattern);
        e.Status = isMatch ? ValidationStatus.Success : ValidationStatus.Error;
    }

    void ConfirmPassword(ValidatorEventArgs e)
    {
        var confirmPassword = Convert.ToString(e.Value);
        bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(confirmPassword, passwordPattern);
        if (!isMatch)
        {
            e.Status = ValidationStatus.Error;
            e.ErrorText = "Invalid password. Passwords must be between 8 and 30 characters long, one number, one lower and one upper case letter, and one special character.";
        }
        else if (confirmPassword != User.Password)
        {
            e.Status = ValidationStatus.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Status = ValidationStatus.Success;
        }
    }


This check happends after submit so you just need to modify the logic of submit. Such as the below editform check password on submit.
<EditForm Model="User" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <Fields>
...
<TextEdit @bind-Text="@User.Password" ... @onchange="()=>{used=false;}">
...
<Feedback>
    <ValidationError>Invalid password. Passwords must be between 8 and 30 characters long, one number, one lower and one upper case letter, and one special character.</ValidationError>

    @if (used)
    {
        <ValidationError>Password has been used </ValidationError>
    }
</Feedback>
...
    <Button Type="ButtonType.Submit">Save</Button>
</EditForm>
@code {
    private bool used { get; set; } = false;

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        //The logic to check if the password has been used
        if (User.Password=="xxxx")
        {
            used = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //old submit logic
        }

    }
...
}

And use "@onchange" event to clear the error when input change.

Thanks for the input. Added it but did not work. I think it is because I would need to force it to validate again? Is there a way to for Blazorise to validate?
